# Given the following WSDL how to call the method LoadStaff()?

Tags: jquery, wcf, wsdl

Following is the WSDL code of my WCF service, how to call the service Directory.svc from jQuery Ajax?
I tried by calling 'Directory.svc/LoadStaff' and 'Directory.svc/Directory/LoadStaff' but I was getting HTTP 400 error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="Directory" 
                  targetNamespace="Directory" 
                  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
                  xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy"
                  xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
                  xmlns:tns="Directory" 
                  xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract"
                  xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
                  xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex"
                  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                  xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" 
                  xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
                  xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
                  xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl"
                  xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
                  xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
                  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" 
               targetNamespace="Directory" 
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Message"/>
      <xs:element name="LoadStaff">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" 
                        name="domainpath" 
                        nillable="true" 
                        type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="LoadStaffResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="LoadStaffResult" 
                        type="q1:StreamBody" 
                        xmlns:q1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Message"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
    <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" 
               elementFormDefault="qualified"
               targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
      <xs:element name="anyType" 
                  nillable="true" 
                  type="xs:anyType"/>
      <xs:element name="anyURI" 
                  nillable="true" 
                  type="xs:anyURI"/>
      <xs:element name="base64Binary" 
                  nillable="true" 
                  type="xs:base64Binary"/>
      <xs:element name="boolean" 
                  nillable="true" 
                  type="xs:boolean"/>
      <xs:element name="byte" 
                  nillable="true" 
                  type="xs:byte"/>
      <xs:element name="dateTime" 
                  nillable="true" 
                  type="xs:dateTime"/>
      <xs:element name="decimal" 
                  nillable="true" 
                  type="xs:decimal"/>
      <xs:element name="double" 
                  nillable="true" 
                  type="xs:double"/>
      <xs:element name="float" 
                  nillable="true" 
                  type="xs:float"/>
      <xs:element name="int" 
                  nillable="true" 
                  type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:element name="long" 
                  nillable="true" 
                  type="xs:long"/>
      <xs:element name="QName" 
                  nillable="true" 
                  type="xs:QName"/>
      <xs:element name="short" 
                  nillable="true" 
                  type="xs:short"/>
      <xs:element name="string" 
                  nillable="true" 
                  type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="unsignedByte" 
                  nillable="true" 
                  type="xs:unsignedByte"/>
      <xs:element name="unsignedInt" 
                  nillable="true" 
                  type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
      <xs:element name="unsignedLong" 
                  nillable="true" 
                  type="xs:unsignedLong"/>
      <xs:element name="unsignedShort" 
                  nillable="true" 
                  type="xs:unsignedShort"/>
      <xs:element name="char" 
                  nillable="true" 
                  type="tns:char"/>
      <xs:simpleType name="char">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:int"/>
      </xs:simpleType>
      <xs:element name="duration" 
                  nillable="true" 
                  type="tns:duration"/>
      <xs:simpleType name="duration">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:duration">
          <xs:pattern value="\-?P(\d*D)?(T(\d*H)?(\d*M)?(\d*(\.\d*)?S)?)?"/>
          <xs:minInclusive value="-P10675199DT2H48M5.4775808S"/>
          <xs:maxInclusive value="P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
      <xs:element name="guid" 
                  nillable="true" 
                  type="tns:guid"/>
      <xs:simpleType name="guid">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:pattern value="[\da-fA-F]{8}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{12}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
      <xs:attribute name="FactoryType" 
                    type="xs:QName"/>
      <xs:attribute name="Id" 
                    type="xs:ID"/>
      <xs:attribute name="Ref" 
                    type="xs:IDREF"/>
    </xs:schema>
    <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"
               targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Message" 
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Message">
      <xs:simpleType name="StreamBody">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:base64Binary"/>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="Directory_LoadStaff_InputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" 
               element="tns:LoadStaff"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="Directory_LoadStaff_OutputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" 
               element="tns:LoadStaffResponse"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="Directory">
    <wsdl:operation name="LoadStaff">
      <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="Directory/Directory/LoadStaff" 
                  message="tns:Directory_LoadStaff_InputMessage"/>
      <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="Directory/Directory/LoadStaffResponse"
                   message="tns:Directory_LoadStaff_OutputMessage"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Directory" 
                type="tns:Directory">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="LoadStaff">
      <soap:operation soapAction="Directory/Directory/LoadStaff" 
                      style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="Directory">
    <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_Directory" 
               binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_Directory">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:59440/Directory.svc"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Here is the jQuery code I used to call the service:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://localhost:59440/Directory.svc/LoadStaff',
type: 'GET',
dataType: "json",
success: function (data) {
//nothing to do yet
},
error: function (SOAPResponse) {
    console.log('oops');
}
```

});

Comment: Rather than posting the entire WSDL (**unformatted** at that!), post your code you're using to call the service - chances are something is wrong in your calling code.

Comment: Thanks for helping me format the code Tim. I'm really new to posting in the site.

Comment: Is your service a SOAP service or REST-based service? Could you post your service definition and your service/client config files?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are doing a HTTP GET request to a SOAP-based service, which by nature always are expecting a HTTP POST of a XML-based SOAP-envelope.

As your client is in javascript your best option is probably adding a REST-based endpoint to the service using either WCF WebGet or by switching framework to ASP.NET WEB API.

If the above is not possible for some reason you could have your javascript client actually make the SOAP-call. Note that this would leave you with a client implementation that would be pretty hard to maintain and also get you into other problems like error-handling etc.

But if you *must* do it this might help you in the right direction:

```
var yourSoapEnvelope = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/X......'

$.ajax({
url: yourURL,
type: "POST",
dataType: "xml",
data: yourSoapEnvelope,
complete: doStuff,
contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
});
```

Comment: The problem is that the service can't be seen at all, neither as SOAP nor as HTTP GET.

Comment: The service you are trying to call (according to the WSDL you supplied) is a SOAP-based webservice and does not expect a HTTP GET which is what your code is sending. So an error is expected when doing a GET to URL "http://localhost:59440/Directory.svc/LoadStaff". What you need to do is a HTTP POST of a SOAP-Envelope to URL "http://localhost:59440/Directory.svc" (notice the lack of LoadStaff)

Comment: Or even better, as mentioned in my answer, if you have control over the service you should change it to or add a REST-based style expecting HTTP GET returning JSON.